# How can you read 0's at the start of an integer or string? To then compare them

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I am trying to code a textField so that is someone put in the number 1 only it will show up 10 and if the put in the number 01 it will show up 01.
The problem I have is that when I code an if statement it can't seem to read the 0 at the start of the number so I end up with 010 or just 1.

I have tried to use integers but get the same result and have tried == and compare for strings but nothing.

```
NSString *millieString = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@",timeFieldMillie.text];


if([millieString compare:@"01"]){
timeFieldMillie.text = [[NSString alloc]initWithString:millieString];
}
else if ([millieString compare:@"1"]){
timeFieldMillie.text = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@0", millieString];
}
```

This is probably because the first 0 is not being read but I can't seem to fix it.
I am trying to make a time converter and this is for the milliseconds so I need it to be 2 digits long.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Use `-isEqualToString:` instead
- You're leaking memory
- The string is reset without the need to do it in your first `if`

Here's a simpler version:

```
if ([timeFieldMillie.text isEqualToString:@"1"])
     timeFieldMillie.text = [NSString stringWithString:@"01"];
```

Or simply:

```
if ([timeFieldMillie.text isEqualToString:@"1"])
     timeFieldMillie.text = @"01";
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch this works a treat. I had originally tried is equal to but the structure of the if statements was making it not work I think. Your help has fixed the problem now though.

Answer (score 0):

Have you try `if ([millieString isEqualToString:@"01"])`?

Answer (score -1):

NSString compare return NSComparisonResult, try use isEqualToString